# vector.back() throws "offset out of range" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, stl

```
void GenerateNativeGamma(vector<float>& gammaNative,
                            float dDetX, 
                            float sdd,
                            float moduleGapX,
                            int nModule,
                            int nChanDetX)
{
    float L = 7*dDetX + (0.78/2+0.11/2);

    gammaNative.push_back(0);

    for (float n = 6.5; n>=-6.5; n--)
    {
        gammaNative.push_back( atanf(L/sdd)-atanf(n*dDetX/sdd));
    }

    gammaNative.push_back(2*atanf(L/sdd));

    if( !gammaNative.empty())
    {
           float lastBonM = gammaNative.back();    // ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!
           gammaNative.push_back( lastBonM +2*atanf(moduleGapX/2/sdd)  );   
    }

    ......

}

int main()
{
      vector<float>  gammaNative;
      GenerateNativeGamma( gammaNative,  1.02,  869.5, 2.087,47, 24);

}
```

I am passing a vector by reference into a function from `main()`; The purpose is to modify the vector inside it.

Then I have this "**offset out of range**" error when trying to get the last element `via vector.back()` like following picture showing:

[image]

The vector is not empty, so it should have a `back()` . Then I have no idea what the problem is here? Or this is not the right way to do it, then how should I modify a vector (dynamic) inside another function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can think of 2 reasons for that: empty vector or memory corruption.

Comment: Just try replacing the faulty line with `float lastBonM = gammaNative.empty() ? 0.0f : gammaNative.back();`

Does the error still occur then?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The thing I think the vector is not empty. At least I see there are 15 elements in it. If it is empty, it wouldn't have hit the line that crashes the program. I put the empty() check there.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think not. Why?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/625da702c36c0922) with gcc, and the code you show looks fine. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If there are 2 or more threads that may modify this vector, that would indeed explain the error.

Comment: @NickXTsui Does it happen if you jut run [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b7985398c80f823).  I cannot reproduce with the code you have.

Comment: Show more of your code. I cannot reproduce with just the code you posted,

Comment: Most likely, the vector is either empty or corrupt. To tell which, we'd need more code, ideally enough code to reproduce the problem. Also, why not just have this function return the vector? Why pass it a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that resizing a vector may cause the underlying array to be moved, thus invalidating all pointers, references and iterators to it. When you push_back onto the vector you've passed via reference it can be resized and, of course, the reference will become invalid.

A quick fix would be to use reserve on the vector before calling the function, making sure enough elements can be pushed onto it without reallocation.

A better solution would probably be to return a copy.

EDIT: a quick example

```
vector<float> vec;
vec.reserve(50);
funcThatAdds50Floats(vec);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds reasonable. By any chance you can post some sample code? A couple of lines would be helpful.